# Help! Magento won't stop sending me new order emails

Tags: email, cron, magento-community, magento-1.9.1.1

I didn't recently upgrade or change any of my settings in Magento, but as soon as my first order of the day came in today, Magento keeps sending me the same New Order email to my inbox. How do I stop it? I'm receiving hundreds every minute.

I really hope the customer isn't receiving them as well.

Comment: Probably truncate `cron_schedule` table to stop the emails. If that doesn't help, disable CRON temporary to investigate the situation. Note disabling cron will also prevent ANY emails going out of Magento like customer registration, newsletter, order, invoice, shipment, etc.

Comment: Please provide which edition and version of Magento you are using.

Comment: How do I adjust my cron_schedule?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Comment: just run `truncate table cron_schedule;` in mysql console or phpmyadmin

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant but I opened phpMyAdmin, now what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin or any mysql software click on you DB which you are using, and then in the upper region you have SQL. Click on that and run command what Kalpesh wrote. truncate table cron_schedule. But this will remove all crons which are in pending state or in progress.

You can disable cron.php on your server to stop running all crons automatically to debug where is the problem.

Another extension which is really good and helpful for crons is AOE/Scheduler. Then you can check timelines, configurations, ....

Hope that helps